# Change behaviour of an event handler in dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, dimple.js

I want to change on click handler and make it work exactly like mouseover works, i.e. show a popup on click event. Can I do something like this?

```
mySeries = myChart.addSeries(null,dimple.plot.bubble)
mySeries.addEventHandler "click", (e) ->
   dimple._showPointTooltip(e, this, myChart, mySeries)
```

Or maybe I can somehow call function __onmouseover from the e.selectedShape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I'm not particularly happy with the way custom event handling is working in dimple. It's a bit buggy and it's easier to do it with d3, I think I'll revisit the whole idea.  In your case I suggest you do it with some d3 after the draw:

```
myChart.draw();
mySeries.shapes.on("click", function (e) {
    dimple._showPointTooltip(e, this, myChart, mySeries);
});
```

[Here it is working](http://jsbin.com/vecoq/3/edit?js,output). I've used the dimple methods to clear the hover tooltips but that may not be a requirement in your case.

Comment: Thank you. And what if I have a line, not just dots? For exmaple, [here](http://jsbin.com/pamiteta/3/edit). How to change event listeners in the case?

Comment: I'm afraid there's a bug with the line event handler: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/75

Comment: Having said that, there's nothing to stop you using d3 for the selection: http://jsbin.com/vecoq/6/edit?js,output